# C# Button with multiple events

Tags: c#, mysql, database, label

I am trying to overwrite a content in an label several times by always clicking the same button. Unfortunately, I only know how to override it once.
The problem I am facing is that the data in the label are from an SQL database and it only displays the data with ID = 1 in the label.

This is my code:

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString); // Connectionstring to the database
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT l_question from l_liescale", conn);

                MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                lbquestion.Content = cmd.ExecuteScalar(); //here I get the data into the label
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to display every data record from the database in one label and always overwriting it with the next record by clicking the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`ExecuteReader()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve collection of data.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var question = reader[0].ToString();
        sb.AppendFormat("Q: {0}\n", question); // use any other format if needed
    }
}

lbquestion.Content = sb.ToString();
```

But the better way is to use [ItemsControl](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/itemscontrol/) or [ListBox](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/list-controls/listbox-control/) or other list-controls.

If you want to iterate by clicking the button you can retrieve all records to the memory and then iterate it in the event handler:

```
private readonly List<string> _questions;
private int currentIndex = -1;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _questions = GetQuestionsByDataReader();
}

private void btContinue_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(currentIndex < _questions.Count)
    {
        lbquestion.Content = _questions[++currentIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: `reader` is `IDisposable`, so,please, wrap it into `using`: `using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {...}`

Comment: "and always overwriting it with the next record by clicking the button"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko TY for your addition it's really necessary to close reader by calling Dispose. I improved my answer.

Comment: @gabba thank you for your contribution, I extended my answer for this scenario.

Comment: @VadimMartynov thank you for your answer :) I only have one question, what is the GetQuestionsByDataReader() ?

Comment: @eCardProgrammer no problem. You can have extra advice by reading about [SqlConnection on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_7). It's a good pracitce to wrap it with `using() {...}` block.
Also, note that accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.
[You may select any answer on questions you asked as the "accepted" answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).